# Devolver mensaje de exito de servlet con libreria AlertifyJS?

Tags: javascript, java

Estoy usando AlertifyJS con Java web, para validar un formulario y me gustaría que luego de que lo valide presente el mensaje de éxito.

He logrado que me valide el formulario, pero no presenta la alerta de éxito. A menos que escriba en el JSP la variable $mensaje y recien me devuelve o dicta que es un mensaje exitoso.

He seguido un tutorial encontrado en google para ver como hacer la validación y quedo algo asi, no se si eticamente esta bien hecho porque es priemra vez que hago algo que no se recargue la página.

**Formulario JSP**

```
<form method="POST" action="agregarMedicamento" class="formulario" name="formularioMedicamento" id="formularioMedicamento" onsubmit="return validar_nombre()">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="precio" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Precio:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio" name="precio" min="0"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="gramos" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Gramos:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="gramos" name="gramos" min="0"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="laboratorio" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Laboratorio:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select name="laboratorio" class="form-control">
                                    <option disabled selected>Seleccione Laboratorio</option>
                                <c:forEach items="${laboratorios}" var="x">
                                    <option value="${x.getIdLaboratorio()}">${x.getNombre()}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="accion" value="Grabar" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Javascript con AlertifyJS**

```
function validar_nombre() {
    nom = document.formularioMedicamento.nombre.value;
    pre = document.formularioMedicamento.precio.value;
    gra = document.formularioMedicamento.gramos.value;

    var form = document.getElementById("formularioMedicamento");
    var errores = [];
    if (nom.length == 0) {
        errores.push("<li>Ingrese nombre del medicamento</li>");
    }

    if (pre < 0 || pre == null || pre.length == 0) {
        errores.push("<li>Debe ingresar el precio del medicamente</li>");
    }

    if (gra < 0 || gra == null || gra.length == 0) {
        errores.push("<li>Debe ingresar la cantidad de gramos que posee el medicamente</li>");
    }

    if (errores.length > 0) {
        var listadoError = new String(errores);
        alertify.alert("Error al ingresar los datos", listadoError.replace(/,/g,"") ).set('label', 'Volver');
        return false;
    }else{
        form.submit;

        return alertify.success("<h3>Medicamento registrado</h3>");;
    }
}
```

Por el momento en el servlet no hace ninguna función de registro, porque quiero hacer que funcione primero.

**Servlet**

```
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            List<String> err = new ArrayList<>();

            LaboratorioService servicio = new LaboratorioService();
            List<Laboratorio> laboratorios = servicio.listarLaboratorios();
            request.setAttribute("laboratorios", laboratorios);
           request.getRequestDispatcher("agregarMedicamento.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Tienes varios errores, el primero es que estás capturando el evento onsubmit del formulario para validar y esa función solo debería devolver verdadero o falso para que se ejecute el formulario, sin embargo, tienes ahí mismo un `form.submit` que, en caso de funcionar, entraría en ciclo o simplemente carga `agregarMedicamento` y termina la ejecución. En todo caso, necesitas ejecutar el formulario con AJAX, para que no se recargue la página y puedas mostrar la alerta.

Comment: @Triby si es que he estado siguiendo unos tutoriales de como implementar el AJAX y no hay caso me enredo solo, he intentado aprender y cometiendo errores, pero funcionaba igual el validar, entraba al servlet pero no podia llamar o imprimir el mensaje con el alertify, estaba pensando en intentarlo con TOASTR porque he trabjado con ese con Laravel y creo que podria invocarlo desde el servlet para que me lo lleve a la vista como en Laravel

Comment: Antes de pensar en usar otras cosas, investiga un poco sobre AJAX, porque realmente no lo estás aplicando, simplemente envías el formulario para procesarse como una petición normal. Puedes comenzar aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX